# How do you debug a custom android module used by react-native

Tags: react-native

Been diving into writing android modules for react but i am having a hard time debugging my native android code...

i can debug the react-native JS without and issue...

Any ideas????

Answer (score 10):

Use the Android logger. For example:

```
import android.util.Log;

// later
Log.e("MyComponent", "Message to log");
```

Then use logcat to watch for the messages you set:

```
adb logcat *:S MyComponent:V
```

Or to see your messages alongside all the other React errors and warnings:

```
adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V MyComponent:V
```